# OO PHP - retrieving all attributes from a class

Tags: php, oop, class, attributes

Is there a function/method which retrieves all of the attributes from a class? Such as all the attributes from my class below:

```
class plantOfTheMonth {

   //Declare which centre(s) are being used
    private $centre = "";

    //Declare the attributes of the current Plant Of The Month
    private $name = "";
    private $latinName = "";
    private $image = "";
    private $imageAlt = "";
    private $imageLink = "";
    private $strapLine = "";
    private $description = "";
    private $color = "";
    private $centres = "";

    //Declare variables for error handling
    private $issue = "";
    private $issueCode = "";

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ReflectionClass::getProperties()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperties.php) from [Reflection API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) or [`get_object_vars()`](http://ir.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) function.

Comment: `get_object_vars()` will only fetch accessible properties, so when called from outside of the object, only public properties will be returned.

Comment: Thanks Crozin, I used this function from the link in the answer above like this inside the class to get around that: `public function test() {var_dump(get_object_vars($this)); }`

Answer (score 0):

A foreach will also do the job, [it iterates trough the visible class properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php).